# What is the difference between CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn and CBPeripheralManagerState?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Not getting What is the difference between CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn and CBPeripheralManagerState? At what situations we should use these variables? 
Can anyone make me understand through Objective-C samples/code?

I am developing an App, where i should know bluetooth power status of my iPhone device through Objective-C. I just want bluetooth power status(ON/OFF).

Answer (score 3):

Basic rundown:

`CBCentralManagerState` is an enum representing the current state of the `CBCentralManager`. The `CBCentralManager` is in charge of scannning and connecting to external devices. It will only be `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn` if the device has LE supported hardware and the user has granted permission to the app.

```
CBCentralManagerStateUnknown       State unknown, update imminent.
CBCentralManagerStateResetting     The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent.
CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported   The platform doesn't support the Bluetooth Low Energy Central/Client role.
CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized  The application is not authorized to use the Bluetooth Low Energy Central/Client role.
CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff    Bluetooth is currently powered off.
CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn     Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.
```

`CBPeripheralManagerState` is an enum representing the state of the `CBPeripheralManager`. The `CBPeripheralManager` controls the ability behind advertising and displaying the phone itself to other LE devices in the area. (ie. the `CBPeripheralManager` allows you to emulate a `CBPeripheral`). It will likewise only be `CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn` if the user has explicitly granted permission previously and the device has LE capable hardware.

```
CBPeripheralManagerStateUnknown       State unknown, update imminent.
CBPeripheralManagerStateResetting     The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent.
CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported   The platform doesn't support the Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral/Server role.
CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized  The application is not authorized to use the Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral/Server role.
CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff    Bluetooth is currently powered off.
CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn     Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.
```

Important Note: Neither of these states will ever be updated if you are not setting the `CBPeripheralManager` and `CBCentralManager` delegates. It is only then that you will receive the respective delegate callbacks where you can check the state of your central and peripheral.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
```

and

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why create a new question?
What I use (well, more or less, I simplified it).
Before doing a scan, I call this :`if ([self isBLECapableHardware]){[self startScan)];}` with `managerBLE` an instance of `CBCentralManager`.

```
-(BOOL)isBLECapableHardware
{
    BOOL        isBLECapable = FALSE;

    switch ([managerBLE state])
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            isBLECapable = FALSE;
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            isBLECapable = FALSE;
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            isBLECapable = FALSE;
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            isBLECapable = TRUE;
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
            isBLECapable = FALSE;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return isBLECapable;
}
```

So, you check `[CBCentralManager state]`and its values can be CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported (which is equal to 2), CBCentralManagerStateUnknown (which is equal to 0), etc.
By *isBLECapableHardware*, I mean "is Bluetooth Low Energy capable (iPhone 4S and newer, iPad 3 and newer, iPad mini etc. which has the chip) and ready to use".

Comment: You're confusing CBPeripheralManagerState vs CBCentralManagerState. They're two totally different things